# Elasticsearch nodes balancing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch cluster with 4 nodes (ES 1.3.5):

**1x c4.xlarge client node**

master: false

data: false

**3x of c4.xlarge**

master: true

data: true

index.number_of_shards: 1

index.number_of_replicas: 2

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

App sends requests to the client node that should load-balance them to different cluster nodes (as i understand). But seems that only one cluster node (that picked as master) handling queries and taking all load.

[image]

How to balance this load to all nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that you can do to load-balance, but i'm also providing some steps improve the performance because just load-balancing will not give you efficiency(and i assume thats why you have a question about load balance).

- Increase the number of shards because you need to have a minimum 4 shards because you have 4 nodes(shard=unit at which Elasticsearch distributes data around the cluster).
- Look into the shard size and adjust and make changes as required (few GB to a few tens of GBs)
- Ideally you need to allocate shards with a factor of 1.5 to 3 times the number of nodes in your initial configuration

Just for reference i'm providing a related and useful article from the creator of Elastic Search - https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster

Comment: allocate shards with a factor of 1.5 to 3 times the number of nodes in your initial configuration. Minimum = 4

Comment: One node - is a client node, maybe it's not needed to include it into calculations? Or it doesn't matter?
I have about 25GB of data placed into 7 types, i've started from 3 shards, load balanced well now. I'll try to increase the number to 6 in the future just to test performance. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should increase your number of shard. One shard means that a single node will hold all your index. Consequently, when a query is sent, only a single node will handle the query.